# Is it possible to use Actions on Google to stream a video to Chromecast?

Tags: actions-on-google

The promotion videos of Google Assistant show that it can stream a video on the family's chromecast. However, https://developers.google.com/actions/ doesn't talk about that feature.

Is this feature already implemented?

Comment: Any update on this? Trying to find an answer now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Although Google Home and Google Assistant can control media devices and streaming - this is not something that works through the Actions on Google API yet. It was mentioned at I/O that there would be an API to send things to a Chromecast display, although the details aren't available.

Comment: Is this available yet?

Comment: No, but this year's I/O begins soon, so we'll see if it gets mentioned again.

Comment: I'm wanting to just showing a video inside assistant (if they have a screen) or Chromecast etc if not. Keeping the user inside the dialog box and then restarting the conversation once the video stops is the ideal UX.